# Attaching a video to static image in angle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photo-editing

We have a video of an app, that we have to attach to an iPhone image(static).
Doing so when the image is right in front of you is easy with iMovie .

When the iPhone on the image is at some angle (like a man holding it) you cant do that with iMovie .

Is there SIMPLE way to do that ? Illustrator? photoshop? (Mac )

Comment: Photoshop and Illustrator are not meant for video editing. After Effects would work, not sure if there is an easier way though.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag and drop the video file into the image file in photoshop and then match it to the orientation of the phone via the transform tools. From photoshop you can export the whole document as a video file.